# Capital Gains tax for Rental House

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax

I have a rental house in Seattle that has been rented for 12 years and is values about $485K.  We bought a house in North Carolina last September and didn't know about being able to roll the proceeds from the sale to our new place and I think we missed the window to do that.  What are other options and how much would the capital gains rate be?

Comment: You still own the rental in Seattle? Is the new place a rental as well?

Comment: Yes we still own and are renting the home in Seattle.  The new place is our residence.

Comment: If you still own both places then what "proceeds" are you talking about? What was sold if you still own it?

Answer (score 1):

If you had lived in the rental 2 of the last 5 years before selling you could have saved on capital gains tax. If you sell the rental and within a certain time period buy another rental then you can defer capital gains tax (1031 exchange).

There's no tax benefit to selling a rental in order to buy a primary residence, so you didn't miss out on anything as far as I can tell.